# Error on getMenuInflater

Tags: android

MainActivity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text.plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Try this e-Learning app!");

    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Home");
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "About");
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Help");
    menu.add(0, 4, 4, "Settings");
    menu.add(0, 5, 5, "Exit");

    return true;
}
```

After adding getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu),

My app's option menu suddenly appears an additional "settings" which isn't functional. I tried delete getMenuInflater() and these related codes, then the "settings" disappered. Is there any solution? please help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPaPZ.png

main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_grid"
    android:maxHeight="32dip"
    android:maxWidth="32dip"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_home"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

Comment: remove `setting` item from `menu/main.xml`. showing twice because __1.__ in main.xml __2.__ Programatically adding  `menu.add(0, 4, 4, "Settings");`

Comment: i understand what you said. Really thank you!  i wanna ask if there are any code for changing the order of the default "Settings"?

Comment: Oh, i finally found out the answer. Change the android:orderInCategory="4" in menu/main.xml